# Multiple file upload in django

Tags: python, django, jquery-plugins, dropzone.js

I need to upload multiple files in my django app. I want to use some sightly jquery plugin such as [jQuery File Upload](https://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/) or [dropzonejs](http://www.dropzonejs.com/). But they are using ajax upload. It's ok when I'm download file to existing model instance but I can append ajax downloaded files in CreateView because model instance is't existing.

So I need some jquery plugin for multiple upload without ajax call or way how to save files to non-existing model instance.

My model.py

```
from django.db import models


class Item(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=256)


class ItemFiles(models.Model):
    file = models.FileField(upload_to='item_files')
    parent = models.ForeignKey(Item)
```

Comment: So... the problem is that you can't save an ItemFile record because there's no Item record yet? Could you just make ItemFile.parent nullable? Or maybe you could *show* what the problem is in a shell session?

Comment: i've never tried this project, but HTML5 now supports multiple file uploads.  https://github.com/Chive/django-multiupload

Comment: dylrei, I can save ItemFile record, i just don't understand how link ItemFile and Item instances together in this case.

Comment: Chris, I tried django-multiupload but its frontend so simple and unuseful for me. I can't choose 2 files one-by-one, only both at the same time.